# What is the memory complexity of this recursive program?

Tags: python, big-o, space-complexity

The following code has to identify separate words from a string (which is without spaces) based on a given word dictionary. It tries to place a space after every character and checks if the word so far is in the dictionary and then tries to form a new word. If the new word is not successful, it tries extending the previous word(s). How do you calculate memory complexity of such a program? Is it exponential/factorial? Does memoization have any effect on the complexity? (assume that is_word() returns if the word is in dictionary in constant time)

```
def word_break(string, dictionary, cache, i = 0):
    if i == len(string):
        return []
    else:
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(string)+1):
            chunk = string[i:j]
            if (i, len(chunk)) in cache:
                return cache[(i, len(chunk)]
            if is_word(chunk, dictionary):
                done = word_break(string, dictionary, cache, j)
                if done == False:
                    cache[(i, len(chunk))] = False
                    continue
                else:
                    done.insert(0, chunk)
                    return done
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

A small note: you never put valid words into the cache; you only put in `False` words. Is this on purpose?

Also, I believe this code will falsely identify the string "n" as a word if you do the initial call the function with the string "bun". Could be wrong though.

The amount of memory that you use is mainly dependent upon the size of the dictionary and the size of the cache. The length of the string will be at least as big as the cache (I believe) and so you only need to worry about the cache.

The size of the cache is dependent upon the exact structure of the word, because what you store in the cache depends on the structure of the string of words.

However, I think you can say that the cache is bounded quadratically ( O(n^2) ) by the length of the string. If you imagine a string where every substring of the sentence isn't a valid word, then it would end up adding every substring of the sentence to the cache, and there are n^2 substrings in a sentence of length n.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it is on purpose. It's because we don't need to put True in the cache ever. We do not need to find all the ways we can break the sentence into words. As soon as we can find one correct configuration, we are done.
No, "bun" will be identified as the sole word assuming "b" and "bu" are not in valid words dictionary, but "bun" is.

Comment: Also, I do not agree with your run-time analysis. The memory complexity is bound by the length of the input string and is exponential in nature, not upon the size of dictionary and cache, as you suggest.